# circular dependency for php-json on RHEL 6

Tags: rhel6

I am trying to install php7 on RHEL6. Can not add alternate channel to RHN , so tried downloading all packages from remi repository and then ran following command:

```
[root@MYSERVER php-packages]# yum --nogpgcheck localinstall php-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-ldap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-soap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-cli-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-odbc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm  php-xml-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm  php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-pdo-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-xmlrpc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm  php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el6.remi.7.0.x86_64.rpm   php-pgsql-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm php-json-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

The output shows `php-json` is needed by `php-common`, however I have already specified `php-json` to be installed

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining php-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-ldap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-ldap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-ldap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-soap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-soap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-soap-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-cli-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-cli-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-cli-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-odbc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-odbc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-odbc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-xml-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-xml-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-xml-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-pdo-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-pdo-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-pdo-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-xmlrpc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-xmlrpc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-xmlrpc-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el6.remi.7.0.x86_64.rpm: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el6.remi.7.0.x86_64
Marking php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el6.remi.7.0.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-pgsql-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-pgsql-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-pgsql-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php-json-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-json-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-json-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Package php-json is obsoleted by php-common, trying to install php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-json(x86-64) = 7.0.23-2.el6.remi for package: php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-ldap.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-odbc.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el6.remi.7.0 will be installed
---> Package php-pgsql.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-xmlrpc.x86_64 0:7.0.23-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (/php-common-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64)
           Requires: php-json(x86-64) = 7.0.23-2.el6.remi
Error: Package: php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (/php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64)
           Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (/php-gd-7.0.23-2.el6.remi.x86_64)
           Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try with "localupdate" instead of "localinstall", and you also need to add gd-last in the transaction

Comment: Thanks Remi , did it with installing just  php-json and php-common in the same commandand rest of the install went super smooth.  Btw, the repo is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier solution would be to add two different repos and then have php5.x and php7.x both running. Local install will complicate things. I have two repos configured in my system (remi-php54.repo and remi-php72.repo). You can find them here: http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/.